# Is it computationally/mathematically feasible to figure out formulas such as this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, programming

So, I am trying to write a program that figures out the correct combination to unlock something in a game. This question is going to need a bit of mathematical knowledge also.

Here are examples of randomly generated formulae that can be used:

Output 1 = (F - (((B + (D - E)) - C) * 1))

Output 2 = (((((((C - (((((F - E) - 5) - 1) + 9)^2))^2) * D) * 6)^2) * 7) - B)

The solution for this would be: C = 8, B = 5, E = 9, D = 5, F = 8 with output 1 being: 15 and output 2 being: 2109

The goal is to write the right combination of the variables B, C, D, E, F to get 15, and 2109 for output 1 and 2. >>You can only use integers 0 to 9 inclusive for B, C, D, E, F<<

You would only be given the goal for output 1 and 2, which is 15 and 2109, not the formula behind it.

My question is, is it possible to figure out an algorithm that can deconstruct a hidden formula such as this? Only one method needs to be figured out, the other formula can use the same method, then a massive list can be compared with solutions for both formulas, finding a match between them. I've messed around with incrementing B, C, D, E, F by 1 and trying to use math formulas for geometric sequences, which doesn't always end up giving the same common ratio therefore can't be a geometric sequence and can't be used... Figuring out the constant is easy, as setting all of B, C, D, E, F to 0 and then getting the result gives you the constant right away. Arithmetic sequences found by incrementing by 1 is also easy enough, but these formulas get complicated, so I'm genuinely wondering if it is mathmatically/computationally feasible to do this? If it matters, i'm trying to do it in python.

Comment: yes it's supposed to use output and variables alone, you aren't given the formula, i guess this answers my question of if it is possible

Comment: From what I understood the formulas are fixed and you have to guess them by inputing digits $B,C,D,E,F$ and see what the result is. So if a variable role is only additive you 'll see the result incremented by a constant each time you increment this variable. And so on... A question anyway, are the formulas only polynomial ?

Comment: that's the idea of the game, messing around by incrementing until you match, i was hoping to speed this process up by working out what variable does what, and then working out a formula based on that

Comment: the formulas aren't always polynomial, but one always is. Output 1 = (F - (((B + (D - E)) - C) * 1)) this is one example, but it would be paired by a more complex one, Output 2 = (((((((C - (((((F - E) - 5) - 1) + 9)^2))^2) * D) * 6)^2) * 7) - B) they both will have to use the same combination of numbers for the variables to get to the 'goal' output of 15 and 2109, the solution is provided

Comment: I don't get 2109 with your solution, I get 1612795.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GiGwsyY.png https://i.imgur.com/lxTJVb6.png i ran this through python

Comment: ^ is bitwise xor *not* power (in python and C) so this isn't a polynomial equation. You should use a double asterisk to mean power if that was intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with arbitrary formulas like this see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation . The problem of finding integer solutions to Diophantine equations is NP-Complete. Essentially that means it's difficult to solve, but easy to verify the solutions, and you can in theory transform these problems into [SAT problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

I recommend using the *z3* solver which has python bindings:
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

Or you could use *sympy*:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html